# Put Multiple XML nodes into previous node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk

There are three type of node which can have 11, 22, 33 and 99. There is no fixed number of nodes.

I have an input like

```
<Input>
    <Line>ABCDEF11XYZ</Line>
    <Line>ABCDEF22XYZ</Line>
    <Line>ABCDEF99XYZ></Line>
    <Line>ABCDEF99XYZ></Line>
    <Line>ABCDEF33XYZ</Line>
    <Line>ABCDEF99XYZ></Line>
</Input>
```

I need an output like

```
<Output>
    <Out>ABCDEF11XYZ</Out>
    <Out>ABCDEF22XYZ/<Out>
         <In>ABCDEF99XYZ></In>
         <In>ABCDEF99XYZ></In>
    <Out>ABCDEF33XYZ<Out>
         <In>ABCDEF99XYZ></In>
</Output>
```

after a node if next node has 99 in it, it should be under the previous node. It can be any node containing 11,22 or 33.

Comment: Your output is the same as the input. And neither of them is well-formed XML.

Comment: Anyway, I believe you will find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343303/how-to-translate-a-flat-xml-structure-into-hierarchical-xml-using-xslt-1-0/53343895#53343895

Comment: Thanks for your comments Michael, At each node, I need to check if the next node has 99 in its value(can be 1 or more nodes), I need to shift it inside the previous node.

Comment: What you show is a (rather meaningless) indent; nothing is being "shifted" inside another node.

Comment: The Answer is Yes, probably even with just the Mapper.  What exactly have you tried?  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: So any line that contains 99 should be a In and otherwise should be a Out?  As others have said, your indenting is incorrect unless you want to end the Out after the In(s) nodes.