# How to COPY same context nodes inside another nodes with xslt

Tags: xslt

I trying to group several nodes that have the same contexts inside a existing nodes, by example my case is try to group node Desglose within Detalle, so by example one Node **Detalle** could have N nodes **Desglose**.

My Actual XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <MT_Request_Respuesta_plano>
        <Cabecera>
            <TipoRegistro>C</TipoRegistro>
            <TipoFichero>Facturas</TipoFichero>
            <CCAA>12</CCAA>
            <FechaFichero>20221124</FechaFichero>
            <DescripProceso>DESCARGAS DEL FICHERO DE FACTURAS DEL SERMAS                                    </DescripProceso>
            <CodigoResultado/>
            <DescripResultado/>
            <espacios/>
        </Cabecera>
        <Certificacion>
            <TipoRegistro>R</TipoRegistro>
            <NroCertificacion>121100</NroCertificacion>
            <NombreSPS>SERVICIO MADRILEÑO DE SALUD                                           </NombreSPS>
            <DireccionSPS>PLAZA DE CARLOS TRÍAS BERTRÁN, Nº 7, EDIFICIO SOLLUBE                 </DireccionSPS>
            <LocalidadSPS>MADRID                             </LocalidadSPS>
            <CodPostalSPS>28020     </CodPostalSPS>
            <FecDesdeLiquidacion>20210316</FecDesdeLiquidacion>
            <FecHastaLiquidacion>20210330</FecHastaLiquidacion>
            <NroLiquidacionDesde>000000000000000</NroLiquidacionDesde>
            <NroLiquidacionHasta>999999999999999</NroLiquidacionHasta>
            <TotalLiquidacionesMes>0000075</TotalLiquidacionesMes>
            <ImporteTotal>000000001498200</ImporteTotal>
            <Observaciones/>
            <Libre>914555222                                                                                                                                  </Libre>
        </Certificacion>
        <Detalle>
            <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
            <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
            <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
            <CodCentroAsistencia/>
            <NumeroFactura>     2110100556</NumeroFactura>
            <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
            <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
            <Nombre>AURORA                                  </Nombre>
            <PrimerApellido>DE                                      </PrimerApellido>
            <SegundoApellido>BLAS GUTIERREZ                          </SegundoApellido>
            <NSS>390050482793</NSS>
            <IPF>113740356H     </IPF>
            <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
            <FechaAccidente>20171107</FechaAccidente>
            <FechaInicioAs>20171107</FechaInicioAs>
            <FechaFinAs>20171107</FechaFinAs>
            <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
            <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
            <espacios/>
        </Detalle>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171107</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.1.1            </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171108</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00011500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000011500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Detalle>
            <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
            <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
            <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
            <CodCentroAsistencia/>
            <NumeroFactura>     2110100559</NumeroFactura>
            <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
            <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
            <Nombre>CLAUDIA                                 </Nombre>
            <PrimerApellido>JIMENEZ                                 </PrimerApellido>
            <SegundoApellido>TORIJA                                  </SegundoApellido>
            <NSS>281208193843</NSS>
            <IPF>111862836B     </IPF>
            <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
            <FechaAccidente>20171213</FechaAccidente>
            <FechaInicioAs>20171213</FechaInicioAs>
            <FechaFinAs>20171214</FechaFinAs>
            <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
            <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
            <espacios/>
        </Detalle>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171213</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Detalle>
            <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
            <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
            <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
            <CodCentroAsistencia/>
            <NumeroFactura>     2110100562</NumeroFactura>
            <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
            <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
            <Nombre>SUSANA SARA                             </Nombre>
            <PrimerApellido>MACHO                                   </PrimerApellido>
            <SegundoApellido>LOPEZ                                   </SegundoApellido>
            <NSS>280343142847</NSS>
            <IPF>170164060F     </IPF>
            <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
            <FechaAccidente>20171030</FechaAccidente>
            <FechaInicioAs>20171030</FechaInicioAs>
            <FechaFinAs>20171031</FechaFinAs>
            <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
            <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
            <espacios/>
        </Detalle>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171030</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.1.1            </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171102</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00011500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000011500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Totales>
            <TipoRegistro>X</TipoRegistro>
            <TotalRegGrabados>0000184</TotalRegGrabados>
            <espacios/>
        </Totales>
    </MT_Request_Respuesta_plano>
```

The result I expect is to be able to group the **"Desglose"** nodes inside the **"Detalle"** nodes, assuming the sequence in which the **"Desglose"** nodes arrive to me, after each **"Detail"** node, could be N **"Detalle"** with M **"Desglose"** associated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MT_Request_Respuesta_plano>
    <Cabecera>
        <TipoRegistro>C</TipoRegistro>
        <TipoFichero>Facturas</TipoFichero>
        <CCAA>12</CCAA>
        <FechaFichero>20221124</FechaFichero>
        <DescripProceso>DESCARGAS DEL FICHERO DE FACTURAS DEL SERMA</DescripProceso>
        <CodigoResultado/>
        <DescripResultado/>
        <espacios/>
    </Cabecera>
    <Certificacion>
        <TipoRegistro>R</TipoRegistro>
        <NroCertificacion>121100</NroCertificacion>
        <NombreSPS>SERVICIO MADRILEÑO DE SALUD </NombreSPS>
        <DireccionSPS>PLAZA DE CARLOS TRÍAS BERTRÁN, Nº 7, EDIFICIO SOLLUBE</DireccionSPS>
        <LocalidadSPS>MADRID                             </LocalidadSPS>
        <CodPostalSPS>28020     </CodPostalSPS>
        <FecDesdeLiquidacion>20210316</FecDesdeLiquidacion>
        <FecHastaLiquidacion>20210330</FecHastaLiquidacion>
        <NroLiquidacionDesde>000000000000000</NroLiquidacionDesde>
        <NroLiquidacionHasta>999999999999999</NroLiquidacionHasta>
        <TotalLiquidacionesMes>0000075</TotalLiquidacionesMes>
        <ImporteTotal>000000001498200</ImporteTotal>
        <Observaciones/>
        <Libre>914555222                                                                                                                                  </Libre>
    </Certificacion>
    <Detalle>
        <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
        <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
        <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
        <CodCentroAsistencia/>
        <NumeroFactura>     2110100556</NumeroFactura>
        <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
        <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
        <Nombre>AURORA                                  </Nombre>
        <PrimerApellido>DE                                      </PrimerApellido>
        <SegundoApellido>BLAS GUTIERREZ                          </SegundoApellido>
        <NSS>390050482793</NSS>
        <IPF>113740356H     </IPF>
        <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
        <FechaAccidente>20171107</FechaAccidente>
        <FechaInicioAs>20171107</FechaInicioAs>
        <FechaFinAs>20171107</FechaFinAs>
        <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
        <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
        <espacios/>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171107</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.1.1            </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171108</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00011500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000011500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
    </Detalle>
    <Detalle>
        <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
        <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
        <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
        <CodCentroAsistencia/>
        <NumeroFactura>     2110100559</NumeroFactura>
        <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
        <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
        <Nombre>CLAUDIA                                 </Nombre>
        <PrimerApellido>JIMENEZ                                 </PrimerApellido>
        <SegundoApellido>TORIJA                                  </SegundoApellido>
        <NSS>281208193843</NSS>
        <IPF>111862836B     </IPF>
        <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
        <FechaAccidente>20171213</FechaAccidente>
        <FechaInicioAs>20171213</FechaInicioAs>
        <FechaFinAs>20171214</FechaFinAs>
        <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
        <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
        <espacios/>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171213</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
    </Detalle>
    <Detalle>
        <TipoRegistro>D</TipoRegistro>
        <ProvinciaOrigen>28</ProvinciaOrigen>
        <CodCentroGrabacion>2803 </CodCentroGrabacion>
        <CodCentroAsistencia/>
        <NumeroFactura>     2110100562</NumeroFactura>
        <ProvinciaDestino>28</ProvinciaDestino>
        <FechaGrabacion>20210316</FechaGrabacion>
        <Nombre>SUSANA SARA                             </Nombre>
        <PrimerApellido>MACHO                                   </PrimerApellido>
        <SegundoApellido>LOPEZ                                   </SegundoApellido>
        <NSS>280343142847</NSS>
        <IPF>170164060F     </IPF>
        <IndicadorRecaida>N</IndicadorRecaida>
        <FechaAccidente>20171030</FechaAccidente>
        <FechaInicioAs>20171030</FechaInicioAs>
        <FechaFinAs>20171031</FechaFinAs>
        <TipoContingencia>AT</TipoContingencia>
        <CodigoContingencia>3</CodigoContingencia>
        <espacios/>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.2.1.1          </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171030</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00017500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000017500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
        <Desglose>
            <TipoRegistro>T</TipoRegistro>
            <CodigoPrestaciones>0</CodigoPrestaciones>
            <CodConceptoCargo>E03.1.1.2.1.1            </CodConceptoCargo>
            <FechaTecnica>20171102</FechaTecnica>
            <CodHospitalizacion>0</CodHospitalizacion>
            <CodTipoTarifa/>
            <Unidades>001</Unidades>
            <PrecioConcepto>00011500</PrecioConcepto>
            <ImporteTotal>0000000011500</ImporteTotal>
            <FechaPublicacionBOCA>20170821</FechaPublicacionBOCA>
            <espacios/>
        </Desglose>
    </Detalle>
    <Totales>
        <TipoRegistro>X</TipoRegistro>
        <TotalRegGrabados>0000184</TotalRegGrabados>
        <espacios/>
    </Totales>
</MT_Request_Respuesta_plano>
```

I've tried this XSLT, one with **for-each-group**, but no result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8"
                indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Detalle">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Detalle | Desglose" group-by="@Detalle">
    <Detalle>
     <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@Desglose">
        <Desglose>

            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </Desglose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Detalle>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also have tried this another XSLT, more nice, but just result with values without label...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:key name="Kgrupo" match="Desglose" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Detalle[NumeroFactura][1])" />

<xsl:template match="Detalle">
    <xsl:copy>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="Desglose">
           
                <xsl:for-each select="key('Kgrupo', generate-id())" >
                    <Desglose>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(main)" />
                    </Desglose>
                </xsl:for-each>
         
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would really appreciate any help to solve this transformation that seems easy, but it is not, at least for me =)

Comment: With the XSLT code matching on `Detalle` but the XML sample not having any elements of that name it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. The `Desglose` your are selecting in the `apply-templates` and you are mentioning in your text doesn't seem to appear in the XML sample either.

Comment: In the end it might be that you are looking to reference or group the `Detail_item` (`Desglose`?) based on the `Detail` (`Detalle`?) elements. It is not clear whether that is just a positional grouping along the lines of XSLT 2/3's `<xsl:for-each-group select="Detail | Detail_item" group-starting-with="Detail">` or whether you want to reference/group based on some of the child element values.

Comment: Neither your input nor your expected output are well-formed XML documents (no single root element).

Comment: If I am guessing correctly, you want to do something very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343895/3016153

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to group Detail_item inside Detail, I try this

Comment: <!-- identity transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template match="Detail">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
<xsl:for-each-group select="Detail | Detail_item" group-starting-with="Detail">
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
  
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail_item"/>
  
    </xsl:template> 
 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments; edit your question instead.

Comment: Thank you Michel , I've edited my  question, I'm new with this xslt, I guess it must be with some <xsl:for-each>

Comment: I gave you a link to a similar question. Try the solution posted there.

Comment: Sorry I try that solution. but doesn't work for my case,,just print values without labels..

Comment: I cannot help you without seeing (1) an example of the XML input (what you posted is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT at all), (2) your attempted solution (following the example in the link) and (3) the expected output. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question with more detail, to see if that's the way it goes, Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioDavidMarínGutiérrez I have posted a correction to your attempt. I hope you take the time to understand how it works. You should know that your chances of constructing a working XSLT stylesheet by blindly copying snippets of code without understanding them are practically nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:for-each-group` instruction requires XSLT 2.0 or higher. To do the equivalent of `group-starting-with` in XSLT 1.0 you need a different method. Your 2nd attempt is close, but it should be:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="Kgrupo" match="Desglose" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Detalle[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/MT_Request_Respuesta_plano">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Cabecera | Certificacion"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Detalle">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('Kgrupo', generate-id())"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Totales"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michel!!!..very nice how you can loop and transform this xslt, and using the key part!!..is amazing for me =)...

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 2.0 answer creates the required output with a recursive named template 'iterate-elements'. The recursive template calls will be 'tail-call-optimised' by an XSLT processor such as Saxon.

I would generally recommend the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612904/63965)'s approach using `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:key` as it it simpler and more concise. This alternate approach is a bit more generic however and may be useful if you find the grouping logic becomes more complex later on.

This XSLT template uses 'recursive-sibling` approach to iterate child element of the root element.

Details on the state that is tracked when iterating each element:

- `$currentElement` the current element for each iteration
- `$targetElement` the last previous instance of the `Detalle` element in the iteration
- `$sourceElements` the `Desglose` elements following the `$targetElement` - later injected into `$targetElement` with the `fn:injectElements` function

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="com.group-elements.sample"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#current"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="iterate-elements"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="iterate-elements">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*" select="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="currentElement" select="$elements[1]"/>
    <xsl:param name="targetElement" as="element()?" select="()"/>
    <xsl:param name="sourceElements" as="element()*"/>
    
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="empty($currentElement)">
        <!-- in case there are any source elements left over: -->
        <xsl:sequence select="fn:injectElements($targetElement, $sourceElements)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="fn:isTarget($currentElement)">
        <!-- on a new target element so process previous target element and set the new target element -->
        <xsl:sequence select="fn:injectElements($targetElement, $sourceElements)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-elements">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="sourceElements" select="()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="targetElement" select="$currentElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- on a new source element so concatanate to the sequence of source elements -->
      <xsl:when test="fn:isSource($currentElement)">
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-elements">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="sourceElements" select="$sourceElements, $currentElement"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="targetElement" select="$targetElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- not on source/target element - process any target element then emit current element -->
        <xsl:sequence select="fn:injectElements($targetElement, $sourceElements), $currentElement"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-elements">
          <xsl:with-param name="currentElement" select="$currentElement/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="sourceElements" select="()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="targetElement" select="()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:function name="fn:isTarget" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="exists($element[self::Detalle])"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="fn:isSource" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="exists($element[self::Desglose])"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="fn:injectElements" as="element()?">
    <xsl:param name="target" as="element()?"/>
    <xsl:param name="sourceElements" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:if test="exists($target)">
      <xsl:copy select="$target">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$target/@*, $target/node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$sourceElements"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>[enter link description here][1]
```

Comment: You say this is an XSLT 1.0 answer - but it contains numerous components that require XSLT 2.0 and will cause fatal error when run with an XSLT 1.0 processor. (Leaving aside the question whether there are any advantages to this approach.)

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for the correction, fortunately,I haven't had to use an XSLT1.0 processor for probably over a decade so am very rusty. I guess setting the version attribute to 1.0 simply enforced a compatibility mode. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Hm. I thought by "amend"  you meant adapt to XSLT 1.0. In XSLT  2.0 you can do simply `xsl:for-each-group select="Detalle|Desglose" group-starting-with="Detalle"`. Why would you need  a 70+ lines alternative?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Good point. Personally, I very rarely use 'xsl:for-each-group'. I find that cases that appear superficially simple (like this)  often turn out to be far more complex in practice - for the grouping key, as more conditions are added using the preceding-sibling and following-sibling axis the code becomes increasingly fragile and harder to follow/debug.  Also, I only need to code in XSLT 3.0/4.0 nowadays so tend to use the xsl:iterate instruction - less verbose than the recursive template I've used here.

Comment: I would wait to see the case before expressing an opinion.