Grouping inside for each loop : xsl 1.0
I have this XML grouped by country. With sequence preserved, the node with a @country value is the parent and the children are the elements with blank country under it.
<catalog> 
<cd> 
    <country>USA</country> 
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist> 
</cd> 
<cd> 
    <country></country> 
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist> 
</cd> 
<cd> 
    <country></country> 
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist> 
</cd> 
<cd> 
    <country>UK</country> 
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist> 
</cd> 
<cd> 
    <country></country> 
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist> 
</cd> 
</catalog>

using xsl 1.0. what I want to do is to group them so that the node with blank country will be grouped under the node with country above it, something like below.



Country
Artist




USA
Bob Dylan,     Percy Sledge,   Joe Cocker


UK
Kenny Rogers,  Bonnie Tyler



This is what I had in mind.
The first foreach loop filters all the node with country, and the 2nd for each loop is to find all the node with the same country and all the blank country under that node.
I'm having issues with the 2nd for each loop. couldn't figure out how to do the loop.
I appreciate all the help. thank you.
<table> 
<tr > <th>country</th> <th>Artist</th> </tr> 
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[not(country='')]"> 
    <xsl:variable name="cntry" select="country"/> 
    <tr> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$cntry" /></td> 
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[country='$cntry' or catalog/cd[country='']]"> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </tr> 
</xsl:for-each> 
</table>


Why is your question also tagged as xslt-2.0 when it says xsl 1.0 both in the title and in the body? This is a trivial problem in XSLT 2.0 where you can use  xsl:for-each-group  with group-starting-with.

Adapting the answer (for XSLT 1.0) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612904/3016153:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="cd[not(country/text())]" use="preceding-sibling::cd[country/text()][1]/country" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Artist</th> 
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="cd[country/text()]">
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select=". | key('k1', country)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


This is best tackled using the technique called sibling recursion, as described for example in Group specific elements in tables with xslt 1.0
The basic approach is:
For the parent element, apply-templates to the first child element.
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <table><xsl:apply-templates select="cd[1]"/></table>
</xsl:template>

For a child element that is to start a new group, create a group, process its first element, and after closing the group, move on to the next start-of-group element:
<xsl:template match="cd[normalize-space(country)]">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
    <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::cd
                             [1][not(normalize-space(country))]"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::cd
                               [normalize-space(country)][1]"/>
</xsl:template>

For a child element that is not to start a new group, produce the output and move on to the next sibling if it isn't part of the group:
<xsl:template match="cd[not(normalize-space(country))]">
   <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::cd
                                [1][not(normalize-space(country))]"/>
</xsl:template>

Note carefully the distinction between following-sibling::*[condition][1] which selects the first following sibling that satisfies the condition, and following-sibling::*[1][condition] which selects the first following sibling provided it satisfies the condition.

thank you. I learned something new today. I appreciate your response.
